# Jenkins booleanParam not working anymore

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration

Since setting up a new Jenkins server with Jenkins 2.55 the `booleanParam` parameter doesn't work anymore. I'm using a declarative pipeline and `booleanParam` worked just fine last week (before updating).

```
pipeline
{
    agent any

    environment
    {
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
        LANGUAGE = "en_US.UTF-8"
        LC_ALL = "en_US.UTF-8"
        LC_CTYPE = "en_US.UTF-8"
    }

    options
    {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '5'))
        timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS')
    }

    parameters
    {
        booleanParam(name: 'DO_CHECKOUT', defaultValue: true, description: 'If checked, source code repositories are checked-out before building.')
    }

    stages
    {
        etc ...
    }
}
```

When job runs, getting the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at hudson.EnvVars.put(EnvVars.java:74)
    at java.util.AbstractMap.putAll(AbstractMap.java:281)
    at java.util.TreeMap.putAll(TreeMap.java:327)
    at hudson.EnvVars.<init>(EnvVars.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
...
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: I think, that by default, even fort boolean parameters, it is a string (because it is injected as an environment variable). You can check this by `echo DO_CHECKOUT.class`. So either check  `if(DO_CHECKOUT == "true") { ... }` or cast it to a proper boolean first. I do not know if this is regression or intended btw.

Comment: @Rik I get the java exception already with just the parameter definition above, not even yet accessing them anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the current version of the Jenkin's `pipeline-model-definition-plugin`. Occurs when an enviroment block with boolean parameters are used in the same declarative pipeline. Will be fixed with version 1.1.3.

See https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43486